# does fastapi contrib has paginator for postgresql?

Tags: pagination, fastapi

I read the fastapi contrib code. Pagination available for mongodb only. Does fastapi has pagination module for postgres db also?

Comment: connections and queries to database is out of the scope of FastAPI right now. There is the https://fastapi-contrib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fastapi_contrib.html#module-fastapi_contrib.pagination class that might be helpful. Currently there's no pre-built pagination solution included in FastAPI.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63476011/fastapi-pagination-error-using-fastapi-contrib/64762432#64762432

Answer (score 13):

You can use `fastapi-pagination` module, it currently has integration with `sqlalchemy` and `gino`.

The usage will look like:

```py
from fastapi_pagination import Page, PaginationParams
from fastapi_pagination.ext.sqlalchemy import paginate


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False)


class UserModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    email: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/users', response_model=Page[UserModel])
def get_users(db: Session = Depends(get_db), params: PaginationParams = Depends()):
    return paginate(db.query(User), params)
```

Please notice, the purpose of this code is to show `fastapi-pagination` API.
You can find a fully working example here: https://github.com/uriyyo/fastapi-pagination/blob/main/examples/pagination_sqlalchemy.py

Answer (score 6):

There is not anything automatic built in to the library, but you can set it up via query parameters and pass it to your ORM, like the query object's offset() and limit() methods in SQL Alchemy.

This example from [FastAPI's Query Parameter Documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/) has them using it on a static dataset:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

fake_items_db = [{"item_name": "Foo"}, {"item_name": "Bar"}, {"item_name": "Baz"}]


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_item(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 10):
    return fake_items_db[skip : skip + limit]
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no built-in pagination system.
You can look at [**fastapi-pagination**](https://fastapi-contrib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fastapi_contrib.html#module-fastapi_contrib.pagination) module. Or you can do something like this:

```
def get_data(database: Session, page: int = 0, limit: int = 50):
    # Note not the best option for large data sets.
    try:
        data = database.query(YourBaseModel).offset(page).limit(limit).all()
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='There was an error while processing your request.')
```

And your API code:

```
@app.get('/data')
def example_data_api(database: Session = Depends(get_db), page: int = 0, limit: int = 50):
    return get_data(database=database, page=page, limit=limit)
```