# FastApi pagination error using fastapi-contrib

Tags: python, rest, sqlalchemy, pagination, fastapi

I'm trying to add pagination to my fastapi project. So I decide to use this:

[fastapi-contrib](https://fastapi-contrib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html?highlight=pagination)

I follow the same example there, but for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
type object 'MOrdenesTrabajo' has no attribute 'count'
```

Here is my code, thanks for your help!!

**route**

```
@router.get("/ordenes-trabajo")
async def read_ot(pagination: Pagination = Depends(), db: Session =Depends(get_db)):
   filter_kwargs = {}
  return await pagination.paginate(serializer_class=OtSerializer.MOrdenesTrabajo, **filter_kwargs)
```

**Pydantic model**

```
class MOrdenesTrabajo(ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
    model = OT # <---Model below
```

**Sqlalchemy model**

```
class MOrdenesTrabajo(Base):
__tablename__ = 'M_ordenesTrabajos'

idordenesTrabajos = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
fecCreacion = Column(Date)
fecModificacion = Column(Date)
estado = Column(Integer)
descripcion = Column(Text)
nombre = Column(String(100))
documento = Column(Text)
fechaOrden = Column(Date)
numero = Column(Text)
ot_padre = Column(Integer)
data = Column(JSON)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [sqlalchemy-filters](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-filters/). I am using it for pagination in my FastAPI project and it works as expected.
My code for pagination looks like this:

```
# pagination
num_of_pages = 0
total_results = 0
if skip and limit:
    results, pagination = apply_pagination(
         results,
         page_number=skip,
         page_size=limit
    )
    num_of_pages = pagination.num_pages
    total_results = pagination.total_results
```